# Running multiple training runs of tensorflow network and receiving huge GPU utilization on the second run

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I am currently training a lot of networks via Tensorflow with different parameters. If I run my script once it the GPU utilization is only around 6%. So I figured I could train multiple networks similarily.
I added

```
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
        print("GPU found. Using GPU")
        physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
        for device in physical_devices:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
    else:
        print("Disabled GPU. Using CPU")
    os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
```

to the top of my script and running only one network still works the same. If I start a second run with the exact same code in an extra screen I receive the following error:

```
2023-05-26 18:09:38.871417: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:226] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2023-05-26 18:09:38.871484: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at matmul_op_impl.h:442 : INTERNAL: Attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestMatrix.py", line 116, in <module>
    main()
  File "TestMatrix.py", line 83, in main
    mnist_DLRT_fr.train(start_rank=RANKS[0], load_model=LOAD_MODEL, dim_layer=i, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name=name, input_dim=INPUT_DIM, output_dim=OUTPUT_DIM, optimizerName=OPTIMIZER, learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, datasetSize=DATASET_SIZE, noise=NOISE, dataset=DATASET, val_size=VAL_SIZE, val_full=VAL_FULL)
  File "/mnt/src/mnist_DLRT_fr.py", line 122, in train
    model.dlraBlockInput.k_step_preprocessing()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 58, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError:  Attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
         [[node MatMul
 (defined at /mnt/src/networks/dense_layers.py:146)
]] [Op:__inference_k_step_preprocessing_823]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node MatMul:
In[0] MatMul/ReadVariableOp:
In[1] MatMul/ReadVariableOp_1:
```

It only works if at the top of the script I only use

```
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
```

instead of which I wrote above. But then the GPU utilization suddenly jumps to 60% and I cant start another process.
Has somebody an idea how to fix this?